# AngularJS - Changing a variable inside a controller method doesn't update the $scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a method in my controller to set to null different variables from my controller $scope. So I've this in my controller :

```
FootCreator.controller('FooController', function($scope) {
    $scope.zoo = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Lorem',
    };

    $scope.foo = {
        id: 2,
        title: 'bar',
    };

    $scope.deleteProperty = function(property) {
       property = null;
    };
});
```

And in my HTML I call it this way (for example) :
`<a ng-click="deleteProperty(zoo)" class="remove icon-remove" title="Remove"></a>`

When I console.log() the $scope.zoo it's not set to null. I think I must do something bad but can't find what. I try to do that not to have a deleteZoo(), deleteFoo() etc.

Thanks for the help/tips !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `deleteProperty` method, you are just setting the `property` parameter to `null` and this is never going to have any effect on your scope.

A simplified example of what you're doing here is:

```
$scope.zoo = { id: 1, name: 'Lorem' };
var property = $scope.zoo;
property = null;
console.log($scope.zoo);  // previous line had no effect on $scope.zoo
```

I would suggest passing the property name as a string instead of the property itself. Then you can do this:

```
$scope.deleteProperty = function(property) {
   delete $scope[property];
};
```

```
<a ng-click="deleteProperty('zoo')" class="remove icon-remove"
   title="Remove"></a>
```

If you really want to pass the property itself (like you're doing in your HTML), you'd need to loop through all the properties to find the one that matches:

```
$scope.deleteProperty = function(property) {
   for (var p in $scope) {
       if ($scope.hasOwnProperty(p) && $scope[p] === property) {
           delete $scope[p];
       }
   }
};
```

Comment: So if I understand what your mean, when I do ng-click="deleteProperty(zoo)" and then getting the zoo object in my controller method I'm not working on the actual $scope.zoo but on a reference copy ?

Comment: @Mushr00m In this scenario `$scope.zoo` is a _reference_ to some object, and `property` is also a _reference_ to that same object. In the line `property = null`, you are changing `property` to refer to `null` instead of that object. `$scope.zoo` will continue to refer to that object. That's how references work in JavaScript. Please see the example I added above at the beginning of my answer.